# phonegap file transfer upload file on server in blackberry

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, blackberry

I developped a phonegap application that works fine on Android and Windows Phone devices. I'm trying now to test it on Blackberry. 
My problem is when I try to upload an image on the remote server, a javascript alert is displayed ("access to "../upload.php"). I added access_shared permission and required plugins in my WebWorks project :

- org.apache.cordova.camera
- org.apache.cordova.device
- org.apache.cordova.file
- org.apache.cordova.file-transfer

I added also, as mentionned in some similar posts, `<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>` in the config.xml and `<access uri="*" subdomains="true"/>` (I tried also with the server uri) but it still showing the same alert.
Any help please? Thanks

edit : I did the same thing in a new project with a new simulator. Now the application can access the server file (and win function is executed) but nothing is uploaded on server without displaying any error.

Comment: which cordova version you are using ?

Comment: cordova.v2.2.0.15 (automatically generated lib when the WebWorks project is created)

Comment: ohh .. use CLI cordova 4.0 +

Comment: I upgrated to cordova 4.0, updated the blackberry10 platform in my project using "cordova platform update blackberry10". So I got cordova.3.6.3 version (as Pinned Platform Versions for Cordova CLI 4.0.0 [http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/10/16/cordova-4.html]). The problem persists!

Comment: have you added plugin for file upload

try this
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Comment: Hope it works .. because i dont have any blackberry device for test :(

Comment: Yes I added it but still not working :(
(I'm testing with a Blackberry 10 simulator)
Thanks Manan